# How to serialize field dynamically if I don't know in advance which serializer will be chosen?

Tags: python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a simple serializer:

```
class BoxSerializer(Serializer):
    modelName = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    body = ???
```

And I want to serialize a field 'body' depending on 'modelName ' field. For example, if modelName is 'Phone' then i want to use PhoneSerializer for 'body' field. If modelName 'book' i want to user BookSerializer and so on. How can i implement this?
Please note that I am not going to save anything to the database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For best practice you can implement :

```
class BoxSerializer(Serializer):
    modelName = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    body = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    def get_body(self,box):
        if box.modelName == "x":
            return XSerializer(box.body)
        elif box.modelName == "y":
            return YSerializer(box.body)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, get the field value and then choose the serializer inside `if else` block:

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def serialize(request, pk):
    box = Box.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if box.modelName = 'x':
        serializer = BoxSerializerX(box)
    else:
        serializer = BoxSerializerY(box)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: You will need a couple serializers for this (obviously)